# When state changes for graphql variable, result stays the same on react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to create an app using shopify graphql api to create an ecommerce app on react native expo.

I have an onPress that calls a setState to change the state of the graphQL variable but the results don't change from the initial state of 'currentSubCategories'

```js
   const [currentSubCategories, setSubCategories] = useState(Categories[0].subCategory[0].handle);
    
      let {
        collection,
        loading,
        hasMore,
        refetch,
        isFetchingMore,
      } = useCollectionQuery(currentSubCategories, first, priceRange);

    const [currentCategory, setCategory] = useState({categories: Categories[0]});


    const onSubCategorySelect = (subCategory) => { setSubCategories(subCategory.handle) }

    onPress={() => onSubCategorySelect(item)}

    function useCollectionQuery(
      collectionHandle: string,
      first: number,
      priceRange: [number, number],
    ) {
      let [isInitFetching, setInitFetching] = useState<boolean>(true);
      let [isReloading, setIsReloading] = useState<boolean>(true);
      let [collection, setCollection] = useState<Array<Product>>([]);
      let isFetchingMore = useRef<boolean>(false);
      let hasMore = useRef<boolean>(true);
    
      let defaultCurrency = useDefaultCurrency().data;
    
      let { data, loading, refetch: refetchQuery } = useQuery<
        GetCollection,
        GetCollectionVariables
      >(GET_COLLECTION, {
        variables: {
          collectionHandle,
          first,
          sortKey: ProductCollectionSortKeys.BEST_SELLING,
          presentmentCurrencies: [defaultCurrency],
        },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      });
    
      let getMoreUntilTarget = async (
        targetAmount: number,
        cursor: string | null,
        handle: string,
        filter: [number, number],
      ) => {
        let result: Array<Product> = [];
        let moreData: Array<Product> = [];
    
        let { data } = await refetchQuery({
          first,
          collectionHandle: handle,
          after: cursor,
        });
    
        ...
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading) {
          isFetchingMore.current = false;
        }
        if (isInitFetching && !!data && !!data.collectionByHandle) {
          let newCollection = mapToProducts(data.collectionByHandle.products);
          hasMore.current = !!data.collectionByHandle?.products.pageInfo
            .hasNextPage;
          setCollection(newCollection);
          setIsReloading(false);
          setInitFetching(false);
        }
      }, [loading, isInitFetching]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    
      return {
        collection,
        loading: isReloading,
        hasMore: hasMore.current,
        isFetchingMore: isFetchingMore.current,
        refetch,
      };
    }
```

I'm using flatList to show the result

```js
    <FlatList
        data={collection}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching) **you have to pass new variables to refetch otherwise refetch will use initial values**.

In this case (custom hook) you have 2 ways to solvethis problem:

- return `variables` from your custom hook (taken from `useQuery`),
- return some own `refetch` function.

1st option needs 'manual' `variables` updating like:

```
refetch( { ...variablesFromHook, collectionHandle: currentSubCategories } );
```

In 2nd case you can create `myRefetch` (and return as `refetch`) taking `collectionHandle` parameter to call `refetch` with updated variables - hiding 'complexity' inside your hook.

**Both cases needs `refetch` call after updating state** (`setSubCategories`) so you should use this `refetch` inside `useEffect` with `[currentSubCategories]` dependency ... or simply don't use state, call `refetch` directly from event handler (in `onSubCategorySelect`).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have an issue now where the data returned is the same as the previous result despite the passing the new variable to refetch.

I checked the console log of the variable before it was refetched and it has been changed to the new one.

Don't understand why it's still giving me the same result

Comment: check 'raw' API responses with dev tools/network or using graphiql, you can also `console.log` received data in `onCompleted` hook

Comment: The results return the same as the previous result unless I refetch it again.

Even as I refetch with different variables, the result returned is always the one step behind, is it something to do with async/await?

Comment: inspect network requests (make sure new/updated variables used) ... but there was many issues related to `refetch`, many closed still reported failing - search on github

Comment: Something weird is happening. Looking into the network requests, it's actually doing two refetches, the first one is the previous variable and the second one is the current variable. But the result is still from the first refetch

Comment: Figured what as wrong, silly error. Needed async and await just variable that was being passed into refetch.
Thanks for your help :)